# Remix not importing all the necassary files

Tags: remix, openzeppelin

I am trying to use the ERC20PresentMinterPauser contract from openzeppelin in remix but Remix is not importing all the files that are necessay!

The code I pasted in a .sol file is given below

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/presets/ERC20PresetMinterPauser.sol";
```

What can be done to get all the files from github to remix for this to compile?

Comment: The contract your are trying to import is in Solidity `v0.8`, what version are you using in your remix contract (`pragma solidity`)?

Comment: not a solution, but it is not a good idea to import from master.. probably better to use a specific tag version, cause they update and restructure their contract a lot.

Comment: I didn't speacify any pragma solidity but after you mentioned I gave ``` pragma solidity ^0.8.0; ``` @alberto

Comment: @MajdTL Yea this is the master branch when I search this in my browser url the repo has all the necessary files

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the remix solidity compiler version to one equal or higher than all contracts you want to include, possibly the latest version